# Why is the "this" pointer in C++ a pointer and not a reference?

Tags: c++, reference

Why is the `this` pointer in C++ a pointer and not a reference?

Are there use-cases that I'm missing that make "this" as a pointer more useful than a reference?

If not, are there any language design implications/considerations involved in having it as a pointer?

Comment: Voted to re-open. As currently stated the question has an unambiguous answer -- which James McNellis posted.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I think people are too quick to close a question that they think can't be answered. If you want to volunteer an upvote for another here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652006/why-accessing-to-class-variable-from-within-the-class-needs-self-in-python

Answer (score 21):

From [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Style and Technique FAQ](//www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#this):

> #### Why is `this` not a reference?
>
> Because `this` was introduced into C++ (really into C with Classes) before references were added. Also, I chose `this` to follow Simula usage, rather than the (later) Smalltalk use of `self`.