# 0 Positional arguements but one given but why

Tags: python

On python 3.3 using Ipython

```
class Gear:
    def __init__(self,chainring,cog):
        self.chainring = chainring
        self.cog  = cog
    def ratio () :
        ratio = self.chainring/self.cog
        return ratio


mygear = Gear(52,11)
mygear.ratio()
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: ratio() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Related question: [Why accessing to class variable from within the class needs “self.” in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13652006/510937)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say

```
mygear.ratio()
```

python will internally invoke the function like this

```
ratio(mygear)
```

But as per the definition of that function,

```
def ratio () :
```

it doesn't accept any input parameters. Change it to accept the current object, like this

```
def ratio(self):
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def ratio(self):
```

You need to put self inside the methods

Answer (score 2):

All instance methods in Python need to take the `self` argument.

```
def ratio(self):
```